# Swipe in tableview not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I do not understand why the swipe does not work? I think I have everything written correctly? Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, GetData, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate{

    //Soccuper des date pour les avoirs en milliseconde

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usersTableView: UITableView!

    //Variable
    public static let db: UserDatabase = UserDatabase();
    var users : Array<User> = Array();
    var filteredData: Array<User> = Array();
    var isSearching: Bool = false;


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //--------Navigation Side menu--------------
        sideView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
        sideView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3; //Opacité des ombres 0.8 de base
        sideView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 0);
        viewConstraint.constant = -290;
        //-------------------------------------

        //------------Searchbar----------------
        searchBar.barTintColor = .white;
        //-------------------------------------

        //----------TableView---------------
        usersTableView.dataSource = self; //Initialize table view
        usersTableView.delegate = self; //Pour le on click
        usersTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        //----------------------------------

        refreshList(); //On rafraichis la listView en mettant a jour les arraylist

        //Pour le seachbar on initialize ci dessous
        searchBar.delegate = self;

    }


    //----------------------Table View-----------------------

    func goToEditFromAlertView(user: User) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addNewUser", sender: user)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return users.count;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (rowAction, indexPath) in
            //TODO: Delete the row at indexPath here
        }
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = .red

        return [deleteAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as? UserTableViewCell;

        cell?.delegate = self; //Pour lui permettre de recevoir un delegate
        cell?.view(with: users[indexPath.row]);

        cell?.myVC = self;

        //Pour changer la couleur de la cellule selectionné
        let bgColorView = UIView()
        bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell?.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView

        return cell!;
    }

    func refreshList(){
        users.removeAll();
        users = ViewController.db.getData()
        filteredData = users
        usersTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
        let searchText = searchBar.text?.lowercased()

        users.removeAll();

        if(searchText == nil || searchText == "" || searchText?.count == 0){
            users = filteredData;
        }else{
            for u: User in filteredData{
                if((u.getName().lowercased().range(of: searchText!)) != nil){
                    users.append(u);
                    usersTableView.reloadData();
                }
            }
        }

        usersTableView.reloadData();
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------
```

I use a customtableview cell.

Comment: Is it possible you include a screenshot of what happens when you try to swipe right - or does nothing happen?

Comment: Nothings happen

Comment: check tableview interaction, custom cell interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this `UITableView` delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

By the way semicolons (`;`) aren´t necessary in swift.

Comment: Not work nothings happens maybe because i use UITableviewcell for custom cell?

Comment: No, it should work with the custom cell too. 
For sure you need to add the method I posted in the answer. Probably something else is missing. 
Does the tableview displays the cells correctly? 
Try to debug the editActionsForRowAt method and check what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 3 & Swift 4:**

You need to implement two different delegates. First one is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Also add the UITableViewDataSource tableView(:commit:forRowAt:) method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  // Action here
  // In case of delete, you can simply do:
if editingStyle == .delete {
    //Remove item at relative position from datasource array
    //Reload tableview at the respective indexpath
  }
}
```

Comment: Not work nothings happens maybe because i use UITableviewcell for custom cell?